# Problemas con los estilos scss de Ionic en dispositivos IOS

Tags: css, angular, ionic, ios, scss

El problema esta a la hora de ver la app en dispositivos IOS (mac,iphone,ipad) pareciera que los estilos css se des configuran solo agarra ciertos estilos, algunas etiquetas se amontonan o desaparecen, pensé que era algo de los prefijos pero no, yo siento que esta en algún import de estilos por que cuando la inició en mac por un instante carga bien la vista y luego se descompone de nuevo, igual probé los imports del global.css pero no,  Alguien podría ayudarme? O orientarme.

html del componente

```
    <ion-header>
  <app-header></app-header>
</ion-header>
<ion-content >
  <div class="bgc ">
    <div class="pt-3  total-center">
      <div class=" recuadro-blc">
        <h5 class=" total-center">RESULTADO</h5>
        <ion-text class="txt-left">
          <p >El artículo</p>
          <p class="lgh">998980 </p>
            <p> tiene</p>        
            <p class="lgh">2</p>
            <p>promociónes</p>
          </ion-text>
        
        <br>
        <h5>DATOS GENERALES</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. artículo </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">9874880</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción  </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">8874880BOTA M28</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. genérico </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">57674875</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">66960</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Departamento </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">356447</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. artículo </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">10302 CALZADO CABALLEROS Y ACCESORIOS</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">DÍAS AMARILLOS CABALLEROS</p></ion-col>

          <ion-col size="5"><p>Valido de </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">24/07/2020</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Hasta  </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">12/02/2031</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Hora de inicio </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">00:00:00</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Hora final</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">24/07/2020</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <h5>DPROMOCIONES COMERCIALES</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">3566</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Clase </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">DFG</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">10%</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <h5>PROMOCIONES FINANCIERAS</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">66960</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Clase </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">Z104</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">09MSI</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <h5>PROMOCIONES CUPONES</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">66960</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Clase </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">Z104</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">30% TC</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <h5>DATOS GENERALES</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. artículo </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">8684880</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción  </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">8684880BOTA M28</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. genérico </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">8684875</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">66960</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Departamento </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">8684880</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. artículo </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">10302 CALZADO CABALLEROS Y ACCESORIOS</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">DÍAS AMARILLOS CABALLEROS</p></ion-col>

          <ion-col size="5"><p>Valido de </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">24/07/2020</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Hasta  </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">24/07/2021</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Hora de inicio </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">00:00:00</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Hora final</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">24/07/2020</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <h5>DPROMOCIONES COMERCIALES</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">66960</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Clase </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">Z104</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">10%</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <h5>PROMOCIONES FINANCIERAS</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">26960</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Clase </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">HJ04</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">09MSI</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <h5>PROMOCIONES CUPONES</h5>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>No. promoción</p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">26960</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Clase </p></ion-col><ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">ZD04</p></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5"><p>Descripción </p></ion-col>   <ion-col size="6"><p class="lgh">30% TC</p></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <p  class="pt-1   total-center">INGRESA EL ARTÍCULO</p>
    <div class="  total-center">
      
      <div class="recuadro-blc-dos total-center">
        <ion-input id="buscador"  placeholder=""></ion-input>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="mt-1 total-center">
      <ion-button routerLink="/login"  color="dark"><p>BUSCAR</p></ion-button>
    </div>
    <small  class="pt-1   total-center">CONSULTA DE PROMOCIONES</small>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

.scss del componente

```
   --AmarilloPH: #EBB349;
}

.total-center{
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
       -ms-flex-pack: center;
           justify-content: center;
   -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
}
p{
   font-size: calc(1vh + 0.8vw);
   color: white;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-weight: bold; 
}
.logo-ph{
   margin-top: 25%;
   width: 45%;
}
ion-label{
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
}


*{
   letter-spacing: 3px;
}

small{
   text-align: center;
   font-size: calc(1vh + 0.8vw);
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   color: white; 
   font-weight: bold; 
}


ion-input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
   color: black !important;
}


ion-input::-moz-placeholder{
   color: black !important;
}


ion-input:-ms-input-placeholder{
   color: black !important;
}


ion-input::-ms-input-placeholder{
   color: black !important;
}


ion-input::placeholder{
   color: black !important;
}
ion-header{
   background-color: #000000;
}
.header-ph{
   padding: 5% 28% 4%;
}
.recuadro{
   background-color: var(--AmarilloPH);
   width: 85%;
   border-radius: 6px;
   padding: 12px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   text-align: start;
   display: block;
}
.recuadro > *{
   color: #000000;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
}
.recuadro > h4{
   color: #000000;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.recuadro > h5{
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin: 8px 0px 6px;
}
.recuadro > h4 > span{
   color: #000000;
   font-family: gothamLight;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin: 10px 0px;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
}
.recuadro>p{
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 10px 0px;
}

.recuadro-blc{
   background-color: #ffffff;
   width: 85%;
   border-radius: 6px;
   padding: 12px;
   display: block;
}
.recuadro-blc>*{
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.recuadro-blc h4{
   font-size: 14px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.recuadro-blc p{
   font-size: calc(1.2vh + 0.8vw);
   margin: 0px  0.2vh;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   color: #000000;
}
.recuadro-blc span{
   color: #000000;
   font-size: calc(1.2vh + 0.8vw);
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: gothamLight;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
}
.recuadro-blc > h5{
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: calc(1.2vh + 1.2vw);
   margin: 0px 0px 2%;
   
}
ion-row>*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
ion-col>p{
   margin: 0px !important;
   padding: 0px;
}
.orden{
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-pack: justify;
       -ms-flex-pack: justify;
           justify-content: space-between;
}
.orden > div >*{
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.orden > div >*>*{
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   font-family: gothamLight;
}

.recuadro-blc-dos{
  
   width: 50%;
   border-radius: 6px;
   padding:8px  12px;

}
.recuadro-blc-dos>p{
   font-family: gothamLight;
   margin: 0px !important;
   padding: 0px;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #000000;
}
#buscador{
   letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.lgh{
   color: #000000;
   font-size: calc(1.4vh + 0.8vw);
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: gothamLight;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
}
.txt-left {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-pack: end;
       -ms-flex-pack: end;
           justify-content: end;
   -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.txt-left >* {
   margin:  0.2vh;
}
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "aplicacion-compras-diseno",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.13",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

estilos globales

```
    /*
 * App Global CSS
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Put style rules here that you want to apply globally. These styles are for
 * the entire app and not just one component. Additionally, this file can be
 * used as an entry point to import other CSS/Sass files to be included in the
 * output CSS.
 * For more information on global stylesheets, visit the documentation:
 * https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/global-stylesheets
 */

:root {
    --AmarilloPH: #EBB349;
}
$amarillo: #ebb349;

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css";
/* @import "~@ionic/angular/css/structure.css"; */  
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/typography.css";
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/display.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/padding.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css";


@font-face {
    font-family: gothamBold;
    src: url(../src/assets/fuentes/Gotham-Font/GothamBold.ttf);
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: gothamBookItalic;
    src: url(../src/assets/fuentes/Gotham-Font/GothamBookItalic.ttf);
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: gothamItalic;
    src: url(../src/assets/fuentes/Gotham-Font/GothamBoldItalic.ttf);
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: gothamNormal;
    src: url(../src/assets/fuentes/Gotham-Font/GothamMedium.ttf);
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: gothamMedium;
    src: url(../src/assets/fuentes/Gotham-Font/GothamMedium.ttf);
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: gothamLight;
    src: url(../src/assets/fuentes/Gotham-Font/GothamBook.ttf);
  }

  *{
    font-family: gothamMedium;
    line-height: 2.3vh;
  }

/* margin total */
.m-1{
    margin: 1vh !important;
}
.m-2{
    margin: 2vh !important;
} 
.m-3{
    margin: 6% !important;
}
.m-4{
    margin: 12% !important;
}
.m-5{
    margin: 20% !important;
}
/* top */
.mt-1{
    margin-top: 1vh !important;
}
.mt-2{
    margin-top: 2vh !important;
} 
.mt-3{
    margin-top: 6% !important;
}
.mt-4{
    margin-top: 12% !important;
}
.mt-5{
    margin-top: 20% !important;
}
/* bottom */
.mb-1{
    margin-bottom: 1vh !important;
}
.mb-2{
    margin-bottom: 2vh !important;
} 
.mb-3{
    margin-bottom: 6% !important;
}
.mb-4{
    margin-bottom: 12% !important;
}
.mb-5{
    margin-bottom: 20% !important;
}
/* left */
.ml-1{
    margin-left: 1vh !important;
}
.ml-2{
    margin-left: 2vh !important;
} 
.ml-3{
    margin-left: 6% !important;
}
.ml-4{
    margin-left: 12% !important;
}
.ml-5{
    margin-left: 20% !important;
}
/* right */
.mr-1{
    margin-right: 1vh !important;
}
.mr-2{
    margin-right: 2vh !important;
} 
.mr-3{
    margin-right: 6% !important;
}
.mr-4{
    margin-right: 12% !important;
}
.mr-5{
    margin-right: 20% !important;
}

/* total*/
.p-1{
    padding: 1vh !important;
}
.p-2{
    padding: 2vh !important;
} 
.p-3{
    padding: 6% !important;
}
.p-4{
    padding: 12% !important;
}
.p-5{
    padding: 20% !important;
}
/* top */
.pt-1{
    padding-top: 1vh !important;
}
.pt-2{
    padding-top: 2vh !important;
} 
.pt-3{
    padding-top: 6% !important;
}
.pt-4{
    padding-top: 12% !important;
}
.pt-5{
    padding-top: 20% !important;
}
/* bottom */
.pb-1{
    padding-bottom: 1vh !important;
}
.pb-2{
    padding-bottom: 2vh !important;
} 
.pb-3{
    padding-bottom: 6% !important;
}
.pb-4{
    padding-bottom: 12% !important;
}
.pb-5{
    padding-bottom: 20% !important;
}
/* left */
.pl-1{
    padding-left: 1vh !important;
}
.pl-2{
    padding-left: 2vh !important;
} 
.pl-3{
    padding-left: 6% !important;
}
.pl-4{
    padding-left: 12% !important;
}
.pl-5{
    padding-left: 20% !important;
}
/* right */
.pr-1{
    padding-right: 1vh !important;
}
.pr-2{
    padding-right: 2vh !important;
} 
.pr-3{
    padding-right: 6% !important;
}
.pr-4{
    padding-right: 12% !important;
}
.pr-5{
    padding-right: 20% !important;
}

.bgc{
    background-image: url("/assets/img/bg-ph-big-2.png");
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
/*  */
ion-button{
    font-size: 1.8vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;  
    height: 5.2vh;
}

ion-button p{
    margin-bottom: 0.5vh;
    font-size: 1.8vh !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white; 
}

ion-input{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: calc(3.8vh + 1vw);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 95%;
}
.button-inner {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.native-input.sc-ion-input-md,.native-input.sc-ion-input-ios {
    color: black !important;
    font-size:calc(1.4vh + 1.2vw);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: calc(3.8vh + 1vw);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.sc-ion-input-ios-h {
    --placeholder-opacity: 0.8 !important;
}
```